# bootstrap 4 body scrolling issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am using my university project for `Flexbox Grid` i added 
`<div class="header">`
`<div id="content-top">`,`<div id="content">` and`<div class="footer">`.

`<div class="header">` is fixed, `<div id="content">` can be `scroll-y` 
and `footer` is fixed, they all are working but i have some issue, body always can scroll i am trying to hide **body** scroll using   `overflow: hidden;` but its not work for me, cannot scroll `content` part, how can i fix it
Thanks

```css
/* Show it is fixed to the top */

body #add-newbookings  {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
  max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0px 5% !important;
  margin-top: 120px !important;
}


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bg-inverse {
  background-color: grey!important;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height:5%;

  background:grey;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card {
  position: initial;
}

#content-top {width: 100%;
margin-top: 2em;
padding:1.5%;
  background:white;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;}


/*--------------------------------------------------Add new booking ------------------------------------*/
/*add-newbooking text fileds*/
#add-newbooking  .form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #464a4c;
  background-color: #f4f4f5;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

/*add-newbooking  creditcardbtn*/
#add-creditcard-btn .btn-primary {
  color: #b89981;
  background-color: #f4f4f5;
  border-color: #f4f4f5;
}
/*/add-newbooking  creditcardbtn*/

/*button cansel-confirm*/
#cancel-btn .btn-outline-secondary {
  color: #343636;
  width: 94%;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #f4f4f5;
  border-color: #f4f4f5;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
}
#confirm-btn .btn-outline-secondary {
  olor: #ffffff;
  width: 94%;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #bda18b;
  border-color: #bda18b;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
}
/*/button cansel-confirm*/

.add-text {color: #232323; font-size: 1.2em;}
/*add newbooking  between textfilds space */

/*/add newbooking  between textfilds space */
/*----------------------------------------------------/Add new booking ----------------------------------*/
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body id="add-newbookings">
<div class="header">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="mr-auto p-2">Dashboard</div>
  <div class="p-2"></div>
  <div class="p-2">Menu</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content-top">
  <div class="add-text">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">Add New 
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
<div id="contents">
<div id="add-newbooking">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">my</div>

      <div class="p-2">  <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">To</div>

      <div class="p-2"><div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">house

      </div>
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">Add

      </div>
      <div class="p-2">000

      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">Add


      </div>
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">Add 

      </div>
      <div class="p-2">00.00

      </div>
    </div>



    <hr>



    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">Total A
      </div>

      <div class="p-2">00.00
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





</div>


<br>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">



    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">Name
      </div>

      <div class="p-2"><div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput-name" placeholder="">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">city
      </div>

      <div class="p-2"><div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput-mobile" placeholder="">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">country
      </div>

      <div class="p-2"><div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput-email" placeholder="">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">email
      </div>

      <div class="p-2"><div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput-notes" placeholder="">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div></div>


<br>


<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">




    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="mr-auto p-2">total

      </div>

      <div class="p-2">$00.00
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap">
      <div class="order-last p-2">
        <div id="add-creditcard-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add home  information</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-2"></div>
      <div class="order-first p-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div></div>


<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div id="cancel-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div id="confirm-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Confirm</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what I have found in your code is a CSS issue. you have

```
body #add-newbookings  {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#add-newbookings /* will be considered as child element of body */
```

**To solve it**

either use

```
body#add-newbookings  {
      overflow: hidden;
}

#contents {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**or**

```
body {
      overflow: hidden;
}

#contents {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: if it solves your question. Please accept it as an answer. it will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please correct `<div id="contents">` as `<div id="content">` and check.